# Selling an imported second hand motorcycle in Pakistan

Tags: import-taxes, pakistan, motorcycles

I'm planning a motorcycle road trip from Thailand to Pakistan for next year, buying the bike in Thailand and then selling it in Pakistan when the trip is done, however my Pakistani friend mentioned selling the motorcycle second hand may be tricky as the bike would need papers allowing it for resale. Is anyone familiar with the motorcycle documents or import taxes needed in Pakistan for general driving/resale?

Comment: There is a lot of discussion about this on [pakwheels](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pakistan+motorcycle+import+site%3Awww.pakwheels.com).

Comment: You'll probably need import and export paperwork for the motorbike, from both the country you're taking it out of and the country you're selling it in. For export, this may simply mean sending a declaration to the vehicle licencing authority in your country of origin. For import you will have to register the vehicle before selling it. Fees/excise duties may also be payable at customs. As mentioned above, a specialist forum or source will probably be able to advise in more detail. (This is based on general knowledge, not specific to the countries.)

Comment: You may need to research the paperwork requirements for transit of Myanmar and India (and Bangladesh) too.

Comment: Consider selling the bike for scrap or parts rather than as a running vehicle. You'll get less, but it might be orders of magnitude easier.